# Is $M_{nj}=(n+1)^j$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, determinant, linear-transformations

It seems that the matrix $K\times K$ matrix $\boldsymbol M$ with components 
\begin{equation}
M_{nj}=(n+1)^j
\end{equation}
is invertible for any dimension $K>0$.

I don't konw how to show this, but it seems natural. 
My first approach would be to show that the determinant is nonvanishing, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\det M=\sum_{\rho\in S_K}\text{sgn}({\rho})\prod^K_{n=1}(n+1)^{\rho(n)}
\end{equation}
or its transpose:
\begin{equation}
\det M^T=\sum_{\rho\in S_K}\text{sgn}({\rho})\prod^K_{n=1}(\rho(n)+1)^{n}
\end{equation}
but I don't see how to go from there. But I think it is already interesting in its own right.

The motivation stems from the following question:
Is it true that for any sequence of real numbers $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\dots, \zeta_K$ I can find a sequence of real numbers $\dots,s_{-3},s_{-2},s_{-1},s_{0},s_{1}s_{2},\dots$ such that $\zeta_k=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} s_{n}n^k$ for all $k$. If the above matrix is invertible, then this is the case since $\vec \zeta=\boldsymbol M^T \vec s $ has a solution (here we just need $s_1,\dots, s_K$, so the other entries could be chosen as 0 to get the infinite sequence).

However this is just the motivation and the initial question is more interesting.

Comment: This matrix is invertible, since it is can be attained from a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
       |M_{nj}|= \begin{vmatrix}
        2^1 & 2^2 & 2^3 &...&2^n \\
        3^1 & 3^2 & 3^3 &...&3^n  \\
        ...\\        
        (n+1)^1 & (n+1)^2 & (n+1)^3 &...&(n+1)^n  \\
        \end{vmatrix}=
$$

$$=2\cdot3\cdot4...\cdot(n+1)        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 2^1 & 2^2 &...&2^{n-1} \\
        1 & 3^1 & 3^3 &...&3^{n-1}  \\
        ...\\        
        1 & (n+1)^1 & (n+1)^2 &...&(n+1)^{n-1}  \\
        \end{vmatrix}$$

So the last one is a Vandermonde Matrix wich is given by:

$$(n+1)!\cdot \prod_{1\le i\le j}(M_{i2}-M_{j2}) \ne0$$

once $M_{i2}\ne M_{j2}$.

Comment: Thanks Arnaldo for your answer. It's great, thanks. I learned a lot from this question. Didn't know about the Vandermonde matrix. On a first reading I always read Voldemort matrix although the words barely look similar.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: sure. Was just about to..

Comment: MSE is in fact an amazing place for learn about math. Days ago I've learnt about gershgorin disk theorem. It was a silver bullet for a tough problem.